# Add one year to datetime row each time the row repeats itself

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Goodmorning everyone. Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df_array = {"date":["2016/11/4", "2016/11/4", "2016/11/4" , "2014/3/2", "2015/5/6", "2015/5/6"],  "id":["1", "1", "1" , "2", "3", "3"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_array)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Which outputs:

```
| id | date      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | 2016/11/4 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 |
| 2  | 2014/3/2  |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  |
```

I want to create a new column called "new_date" which takes the date in the "date" column from each unique row, transorms it in the first day of that year, and then add one year every time the row repeats, like so:

```
| id | date      | new_date |
|----|-----------|----------|
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2016/1/1 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2017/1/1 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2018/1/1 |
| 2  | 2014/3/2  | 2014/1/1 |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  | 2015/1/1 |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  | 2016/1/1 |
```

I can run something like this to create the new_date column and fill it like so:

```
df["new_date"] = df.drop_duplicates()["date"].dt.year.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x, 1, 1))
```

Which outputs:

```
| id | date      | new_date |
|----|-----------|----------|
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2016/1/1 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2016/1/1 |
| 1  | 2016/11/4 | 2016/1/1 |
| 2  | 2014/3/2  | 2014/1/1 |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  | 2015/1/1 |
| 3  | 2015/5/6  | 2015/1/1 |
```

But then I'm not sure how to proceed to increment the date each times the rows repeat themselves. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per groups for counter of years, add to years and last convert to datetimes:

```
y = df['date'].dt.year
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.groupby(y).cumcount() + y, format='%Y')
print (df)
        date id   new_date
0 2016-11-04  1 2016-01-01
1 2016-11-04  1 2017-01-01
2 2016-11-04  1 2018-01-01
3 2014-03-02  2 2014-01-01
4 2015-05-06  3 2015-01-01
5 2015-05-06  3 2016-01-01
```

Or you can specify months with days:

```
y = df['date'].dt.year
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime((df.groupby(y).cumcount() + y).astype(str) + '-01-01')
```